# "день" "дней" при разных значениях поля отчета календаря

Tags: javascript, php

Есть скрипт обратного отчета даты. Нужно при разных значениях выводить либо "дней", либо "дня". "осталось 2 дня","осталось 10 дней". Как можно это реализовать?

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <div class="countdown-digits">10</div>
  <div class="countdown-label">дней</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Миллион ответов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Ещё лучше - поискать "число прописью" (а хоть и в гугле), и ПОНЯТЬ, как работает найденный код.

Answer (score 1):

```
function decl($n, $str_cases)
{
  $cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return  $str_cases[ (($n % 100 ) > 4 && ($n % 100) < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min(($n % 10), 5)] ];
}


print_r(
  decl(10, ['День', 'Дня', 'Дней'])
);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Об каких нюансах? это самодостаточный воспроизведимый пример, который решает вопрос пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Можно к примеру сделать условие при выводе:

```html
<? foreach($days as $day): ?>
  <? switch(true): ?>
    <? case ($day == 1 || $day == 21 || $day == 31): ?>
      <? $caption = 'день'; break; ?>
    <? case (in_array($day, [2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 24])): ?>
      <? $caption = 'дня'; break; ?>
    <? default: ?>
      <? $caption = 'дней'; ?>
  <? endswitch; ?>
  <div class="countdown">
    <div class="countdown-digits"><?= $day; ?></div>
    <div class="countdown-label"><?= $caption; ?></div>
  </div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```